# What is the difference between these circuit?

Tags: capacitor

Is there any difference between these circuit in Theory and action and Modeling?

(two capacitors are equal).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming 0 resistance and inductance, absolutely nothing.

Comment: And assuming the capacitor is physically small enough that the lumped-element approximation is still valid.

Comment: @ The Photon.Whats will be the differens If capacitor is not physically small?

Comment: @musefian, if it's not physically small, then it's a transmission line or a resonant cavity, or both.  Treating a capacitance as "pure C" is an approximation.

Comment: To be sure, we need the capacitor to be *electrically* small which is to say that the capacitor's physical dimensions are *much* smaller than the electrical wavelength of the signals of interest.  In other words, and as The Photon correctly points out, when the lumped element model is a good approximation.  From the relevant Wikipedia article:  *The lumped element model is valid whenever \$L_c \ll \lambda\$, where \$L_c\$ denotes the circuit's characteristic length, and \$\lambda\$ denotes the circuit's operating wavelength.*

Answer (score 3):

Physically, nothing at all.

Technically, the second one does not use the common symbol for the capacitor (assuming it should still represent one).

Answer (score 2):

In the circuit design and the construction thereof, where converge the conductors or copper wires, etc .., are called "nodes" in these potential relative to ground is the same and is satisfied the law of Kirchhoff currents, in the drawings the capacitor is between the same nodes are therefore equal electronically.